# I want to sort first 6 element but it is sorting and displaying all element

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, sorting, slice

I fetched data in loadAllData(limit) function with a parameter. And call the function end of the code. In the first step i call loadAllData(6) so that it will show first 6 element and when show more button clicekd it call loadAllData() without parameter. in displayAllData(data, limit) it checked if there is limit than it split the array to 6 or loop through the data(array).

```
const loadAllData = (limit) => {
    const url = 'https://openapi.programming-hero.com/api/ai/tools';
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => displayAllData(data.data.tools, limit))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

```
const displayAllData = (data, limit) => {

    const cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
    // cardContainer.innerText = '';
    
    if(limit && data.length >=6) {
        cardContainer.innerText = '';
        document.getElementById('showMoreBtn').classList.remove('d-none');
        data = data.slice(0, 6);
    }
    else {
        cardContainer.innerText = '';
        document.getElementById('showMoreBtn').classList.add('d-none');
    }
    
    for (const element of data) {
        //It works fine
    }
}

loadAllData(6);
```

```
document.getElementById('showMoreBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('loaderDiv').classList.add('d-block');
    document.getElementById('showMoreBtn').classList.add('d-none');
    loadAllData();
})
```

When 'sort by date' called it passed the sorted data to displayAllData(data). Now the problem is after show more button clicked or expand all data that time 'sort by date' works fine. but when 'sort by date' clicked on deafult 6 elements. It also showed all data and make sorted as well.

```
const sortFunction = (data) => {
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var c = new Date(a.published_in);
        var d = new Date(b.published_in);
        return d - c;
    });

    displayAllData(data);
}
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

I tried to sort the first (initial) 6 elements; but when i clicked on 'sort by date' it sorted all data and display all data.

Comment: You don't show _how_ `sortFunction` is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` sorts the array in-place and mutates the original array. You should make a (shallow) copy of the data array before sorting it.

```js
const sortFunction = (data) => {
    const copy = [...data]; // or data.slice(0)

    copy.sort(function (a, b) {
        var c = new Date(a.published_in);
        var d = new Date(b.published_in);
        return d - c;
    });

    displayAllData(copy);
};
```

Comment: My sort function is working fine but the problem is when i am trying to sort of default(6) elements that time it sorted all data and displayed as well.